# Rounding amount with available set of denominations

Tags: c#, algorithm

This isn't regular rounding thing which rounds up or down based of a single value.
I would want to have a function where I pass the amount as integer and denominations as array of integer.
What that function should return to me is a nearest possible integer value achievable with passed array of denominations.
Whether to round up or down will again be sent as a parameter.

**Code:**

```
var amount = 61; // for. e.g.
int[] denoms = [20, 50]; // for. e.g.
bool roundUp = true;
amount = RoundAmount(amount, denoms, roundUp);
```

**Expected result :**

`RoundAmount` function should return me the nearest possible amount achievable with denoms that I have passed.

1. If `roundUp = true`, The return value should be `70`, because `70 = 20+50`
   and amount `70` can be achieved by one note of 20s and one note of 50s.
2. If `roundUp = false`, It should have returned `60`, because `60 =
   20+20+20` and amount `60` can be achieved by 3 notes of 20s

**What I got so far :**

I was only reached to the point where I can manage to round the amount up or down based on a single integer (and not the array of integers)

```
public int RoundAmount(int amount, int value, bool roundUp)
{
   if (roundUp)
      amount = amount - (amount % value) + value;
   else
      amount = amount - (amount % value)

   return amount;
}
```

**Edit:**

I have another recursive function which checks if amount is achievable or not,
Only if amount isn't achievable, `RoundAmount` function is called.

So in my example, `amount = 70` will never be the input because `70` is achievable with available denoms and I won't call the `RoundAmount` in that case.

**Solution:** (Thanks to maraca and Koray)

I'm glad its working with `long` numbers though it wasn't original requirement.

```
private static long RoundAmount_maraca(long a, long[] d, bool up)
{
    d = d.ToArray();
    Array.Sort(d);

    if (a < d[0])
        return up ? d[0] : 0;
    long count = 0;
    for (long i = 0; i < d.Length; i++)
    {
        if (d[i] == 0)
            continue;
        for (long j = i + 1; j < d.Length; j++)
            if (d[j] % d[i] == 0)
                d[j] = 0;
        if (d[i] > a && !up)
            break;
        d[count++] = d[i];
        if (d[i] > a)
            break;
    }
    if (count == 1)
        return (!up ? a : (a + d[0] - 1)) / d[0] * d[0];
    long gcd = euclid(d[1], d[0]);
    for (long i = 2; i < count && gcd > 1; i++)
        gcd = euclid(d[i], gcd);
    if (up)
        a = (a + gcd - 1) / gcd;
    else
        a /= gcd;
    for (long i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        d[i] /= gcd;
        if (a % d[i] == 0)
            return a * gcd;
    }
    var set = new HashSet<long>();
    set.Add(0);
    long last = 0;
    for (long n = d[0]; ; n++)
    {
        if (!up && n > a)
            return last * gcd;
        for (long i = 0; i < count && n - d[i] >= 0; i++)
        {
            if (set.Contains(n - d[i]))
            {
                if (n >= a)
                    return n * gcd;
                if ((a - n) % d[0] == 0)
                    return a * gcd;
                set.Add(n);
                last = n;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
private static long euclid(long a, long b)
{
    while (b != 0)
    {
        long h = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = h;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: In roundUp why you added array values and in roundDown why you added array first element 3 times. Justify that point and we may come in conclusion or say your requirement.

Comment: I have updated expected result in question to answer you @bhushan

Comment: Can you predict the max amount, expected number of denominations and their range? Or do you want to create a method that choses the best combination of algorithms based on input?

Comment: What strategy do you want if there are more than one solution? For example, if I had the `denoms = { 10, 20, 50 }` then I could have `{ 10, 50 }` or `{ 20, 20, 20 }`.

Comment: @Enigmativity Sets of possible combinations really don't matter, What I only need is nearest achievable amount, either up or down, by any set of denoms. Hope i'm clear :)

Comment: So far all I can tell is that the test is very bad. With {2, 3} you can build all numbers except 1, the rest doesn't even matter. My algo would return after at most 3 steps, no matter how big the amount is and what other numbers follow 2 and 3. If you want to check performance for bad cases the amount has to be unachievable.

Comment: a = 19386601, d = {130091, 156091, 195169, 221143, 286039}. Down: 19386588, Up: 19386614.

Comment: If there are really such large differences between a and d you can check (after nomalization by gcd) if a > d[0] * d[1] - d[0] - d[1] (the formula for the Frobenius number for 2 denominations, take the smallest ones to get best estimation, adding more denominations can only decrease the Frobenius number) and return a * gcd immediately. So for an a of 10^18 to be unreachable, the denominations have to be > 10^9 (assuming gcd is 1).

Comment: @PravinDeshmukh there might be a problem: a=790708, d={68, 76}, roundUp=true -> should be 790708; but with your code I get 790712. + If denoms contains 0, exception occurs.

Comment: @PravinDeshmukh during my tests, I saw that your last edit is slower than maraca's code. At the momet, if int value type is enough, my update **Edit 7** seems to be faster. However mine cannot be converted to long value type. If long is the requirement, maraca's code is the right way to go; I think.

Comment: @Koray I checked again and it returned me 790708. Also denoms contains 0 is not a valid business scenario (though it's just about adding one more check)

Comment: @PravinDeshmukh  try amount = 120700011; denoms =  { 50, 62 }; roundup=true 120700022  returns not 120700012.

Comment: @Koray Yes, As I anticipated my solution isn't accurate at all. Just now I was comparing performances of `RoundAmount_Koray` and `RoundAmount-Maraca`, with unachievable small numbers `RoundAmount_Koray` did well, but with unachievable long numbers `RoundAmount_maraca` outperformed with utmost accuracy :)

Comment: And I test your code, if you could solve that bug (if it is) your code outperformed all (most of the time in the random test)

Comment: Yea, What i'm doing there is setting the lower bound on `hsOK`, which will always be calculated wrong if I don't traverse through all denoms and their different sums (combinations)

Any how, maracas code took less than 500ms when `a = 98765432123456789 and d = {130091, 156091, 195169, 221143, 286039}` and I'm more than happy with it's performance and accuracy :) Very thankful for efforts you both have taken to optimize this. Cheers!

Comment: @PravinDeshmukh OK I had a look. It is very similar, except that you test all denominations for modulo, which could return earlier if the number can be built, but will be worse when the amount cannot be built, especially if there are a lot of denominations. That's why I only do d[0]. Originally I tried to find the Frobenius number, but with modulo d[0] it is guaranteed you return before finding the Frobenius number, if the amount can be built.

Comment: @Koray your algorithm can be used with longs too, but you have to replace the bit aray by a hash set. Which makes me wonder how much difference bit array vs. hash set makes.

Comment: @maraca I have used bitarray because it uses much less memory and is faster. I have tried to write a ulong version for bitarray and applied it your latest update :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming that you are looking for a performant solution with a relatively small amount of denominations `b` (e.g. less than 100 denominations). While the amount `a` and the denominations `d[i]` can be quite large (e.g. less than 10^6).

1. Sort `d` ascending and remove duplicates. When rounding down only keep the values smaller or equal than `a` and when rounding up keep only the smallest value greater or equal than `a` and discard the greater ones.
2. (Optional) remove all numbers which are a multiple of some other number O(b^2).
3. Calculate the greatest common divisor `gcd` of the denominations. You can use the Euclidean algorithm starting with the first two numbers then calculate the greatest common divisor of the result and the third number and so on. Of course you can stop as soon as you reach one.
4. Divide `a` by `gcd`, round like you want to round the result (using integer division, rounding down: `a /= gcd`, rounding up: `a = (a + gcd - 1) / gcd`).
5. Divide all denominations by `gcd` (`d[i] /= gcd`). Now the greatest common divisor of all denominations is one and therefore it is guaranteed that a Frobenius number exists (all amounts greater than that number can be built and require no rounding). While doing so you can also check if the new value leads to `a % d[i] == 0` and immediately return `a * gcd` if so.
6. Create a hash `set` for the values which can be built. It is better than an array because the array is potentially wasting a lot of space (remember the Frobenius number). Add zero to the set.
7. Create a variable `n` for the current number, initialize with smallest denomination: `n = d[0]`.
8. If `n` can be built with any of the available denominations, in other words the `set` contains any of `n - d[i]` then proceed with the next step. Otherwise increase `n` by one and repeat this step unless `n == a` and you are rounding down, then you can return the last number that could be built multiplied by `gcd` immediately. You could also remove `n - d[b - 1]` from the `set` each time because this value will not be requested any more.
9. If `n >= a` return `n * gcd` (can only be true when rounding up, rounding down would have returned the result in step 8. already). Else if `(a - n) % d[0] == 0` return `a * gcd`. This check is even better than looking for the Frobenius number (the number after which `d[0] - 1` consecutive values can be built), it is more or less the equivalent (`d[0] - 1` consecutive values means the difference between one of them and `a` modulo `d[0]` has to be zero) but could return much faster. Else increase `n` by one and continue with step 8.

An example with d = {4, 6} and a = 9999 (or any other big odd number) shows the advantages of this algorithm. It is easy to see that odd numbers can never be built and we would fill up the whole set with all even numbers except 2. But if we divide by gcd we get d = {2, 3} and aUp = 5000 and aDown = 4999. The Frobenius number for {2, 3} is 1 (the only number which cannot be built), so after at most 3 (first number where all modulos are covered) steps (instead of 10000) the modulo would be zero and we would return a * gcd which gives 9998 or 10000 depending on rounding direction, which is the correct result.

---

Here is the code with test included. I did six runs on my crappy notebook and it took 90, 92, 108, 94, 96 and 101 seconds (**edit**: early loop escape if current denomination greater than current number `&& n - d[i] >= 0` halves the times and gives an average of about **45s**) for 7200 random roundings (3600 in each direction) with combinations of different amounts of denominations (range 2 to 100), dMax (range 100 to 10^6) and aMax (range 10^4 to 10^6), (see the code at the bottom for the exact values). I think the time for the random number generation and output can be neglected, so with this input and the given ranges the algorithm rounds about *160 numbers per second* on average (**edit: see thirty times faster version below**).

```java
public static final int round(int a, int[] d, boolean up) {
    d = d.clone(); // otherwise input gets changed
    Arrays.sort(d);
    if (a < d[0])
        return up ? d[0] : 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
        if (d[i] == 0)
            continue;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < d.length; j++)
            if (d[j] % d[i] == 0)
                d[j] = 0;
        if (d[i] > a && !up)
            break;
        d[count++] = d[i];
        if (d[i] > a)
            break;
    }
    if (count == 1)
        return (!up ? a : (a + d[0] - 1)) / d[0] * d[0];
    int gcd = euclid(d[1], d[0]);
    for (int i = 2; i < count && gcd > 1; i++)
        gcd = euclid(d[i], gcd);
    if (up)
        a = (a + gcd - 1) / gcd;
    else
        a /= gcd;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        d[i] /= gcd;
        if (a % d[i] == 0)
            return a * gcd;
    }
    Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    set.add(0);
    int last = 0;
    for (int n = d[0];; n++) {
        if (!up && n > a)
            return last * gcd;
        for (int i = 0; i < count && n - d[i] >= 0; i++) {
            if (set.contains(n - d[i])) {
                if (n >= a)
                    return n * gcd;
                if ((a - n) % d[0] == 0)
                    return a * gcd;
                set.add(n);
                last = n;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static final int euclid(int a, int b) {
    while (b != 0) {
        int h = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = h;
    }
    return a;
}

public static final int REPEAT = 100;
public static final int[] D_COUNT = {2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100};
public static final int[] D_MAX = {100, 10000, 1000000};
public static final int[] A_MAX = {10000, 1000000};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < REPEAT; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < D_COUNT.length; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < D_MAX.length; k++) {
                for (int l = 0; l < A_MAX.length; l++) {
                    int[] d = new int[D_COUNT[j]];
                    for (int m = 0; m < d.length; m++)
                        d[m] = r.nextInt(D_MAX[k]);
                    int a = r.nextInt(A_MAX[l]);
                    System.out.println(round(a, d, false));
                    System.out.println(round(a, d, true));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000 + " seconds");
}
```

---

As it turns out **@Koray's edit 7 is about three times faster** for the given input (only for very large gcds my algorithm above is faster). So to get the ultimate algorithm **I replaced the dynamic programming part of my algorithm by that of @Koray** (with some improvements). It worked, it is roughly ten times faster than edit 7 and **thirty times faster than the algorithm above**. Which would give about *5000 roundings per second* (very rough estimation) on average.

```
private static int round(int a, int[] d, boolean up) {
    d = d.clone();
    Arrays.sort(d);
    if (a < d[0])
        return up ? d[0] : 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
        if (d[i] == 0)
            continue;
        if (a % d[i] == 0)
            return a;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < d.length; j++)
            if (d[j] > 0 && d[j] % d[i] == 0)
                d[j] = 0;
        if (d[i] > a && !up)
            break;
        d[count++] = d[i];
        if (d[i] > a)
            break;
    }
    if (count == 1)
        return (!up ? a : (a + d[0] - 1)) / d[0] * d[0];
    int gcd = euclid(d[1], d[0]);
    for (int i = 2; i < count && gcd > 1; i++)
        gcd = euclid(d[i], gcd);
    if (gcd > 1) {
        if (up)
            a = (a + gcd - 1) / gcd;
        else
            a /= gcd;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            d[i] /= gcd;
            if (a % d[i] == 0)
                return a * gcd;
        }
    }
    int best = !up ? d[count - 1] : ((a + d[0] - 1) / d[0] * d[0]);
    if (d[count - 1] > a) {
        if (d[count - 1] < best)
            best = d[count - 1];
        count--;
    }
    Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<Integer>();
    BitSet ba = new BitSet(a + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        ba.set(d[i]);
        st.push(d[i]);
    }
    while (st.size() > 0) {
        int v1 = st.pop();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            int val = v1 + d[i];
            if (val <= a && !ba.get(val)) {
                if ((a - val) % d[0] == 0)
                    return a * gcd;
                ba.set(val, true);
                st.push(val);
                if (!up && val > best)
                    best = val;
            } else if (val > a) {
                if (up && val < best)
                    best = val;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return best * gcd;
}
```

Comment: Looks promising. The fact that it does other checks such as removing multiple of denoms, calculating gcd makes it more interesting. I'm trying this one, will inform the results. Thanks

Comment: This is the only answer that seems to correctly identify this as simply a GCD+rounding problem.  Correctly implementing this will result in the fastest solution (`O(n*log(n))` where `n` is the number of denominations).

Comment: @RBarryYoung yes it is a gcd rounding problem if (and that's the problem) the amount is bigger than the Frobenius number of the denominations (after normalization by gcd). The only known formula to calculate the Frobenius number directly is for two denominations: d1*d2 - d1 - d2. Even if we had the formula for more denominations, if the amount is smaller than that we have to do it in any of the dp ways.

Comment: @maraca try a=10, d={9}, up=false

Comment: @Koray you are right, I corrected it, one check removed, 2 added in the O(1) part, shouldn't affect times at all. (Correction had a bug too, +1 instead of -1, corrected again).

Comment: wow +1 This is just great! If you'd fix that little bug, your code is >6 times faster than my try.

Comment: Some cases its >6300 faster. Congratulations.

Comment: @Koray thanks, but you can construct cases where your method is faster. E.g. for a small number of large coprime denominations and large unconstructable amounts.

Comment: @Koray missed obvious optimization and could halve the times by an additon of some characters.

Comment: @maraca thanks for sharing the code. It's a beauty. I'll examine it more when I sleep and find time again :)

Comment: @maraca Please check solution update on my question. Notice the code section `// Set Lowerbound` I'm hoping to hear a feedback from you, also expecting your suggestions

Comment: @maraca Please check my last update **Edit 7** I hope I haven't done something wrong while converting your code to c#.

Comment: @maraca competition continues.. **Edit 8** is my latest attack :)

Comment: @Koray I had a look at it. You implement the stack as ArrayList (or Vector), but with primitive types, that's why it is probably faster than the standard implementation. Btw. I'm wondering about the long solution, can a bit array in C# declared like this hold bigger values than the size of ints or not? In Java it is not possible, we could use a HashSet<Long> instead, which only holds Integer.MAX_VALUE entries (but only the ones that can be built, not all of them like the bit array), so it can work for longs (big numbers means big gaps), but not for all longs.

Comment: @Koray Taking my latest rounding function with your Stack class should give even faster results, because I cannot imagine that creating a stack and scanning for the best value or a bit array potentially almost double in size of what is needed is faster. I didn't think Stack is that bad in terms of performance. If I'm wrong then it must be that your modulo check is better than mine or the gain through gcd calculation is not enough in general, because gcd is too often 1.

Comment: @maraca as I mentioned, my last upted outperforms not because of the stack implementation. You can try it with the standard Stack<> class -see my performance measurements. Btw my stack class is just a modified version of .NET's original class, and is just an extra boost; you may apply it as well. I haven't tried a long version, but it can easily be applied with my ulong version of bitarray **UlongBitArray** of my previous update. I have used shifting bits for that, and it passed my some heavy tests. I couln't understood everything you write, I expect an update of you to outperform mine soon :)

Comment: @Koray I don't really see it. I added early escape before gcd calculation too, but it had no effect (updated code anyways). Measured gcd calculation itself, negligible. Compared my modulo escape to yours (mine was better). So I don't see what it could be except the stack, because I am pretty sure that your method with only a bit array of size amount + 1 and no hsOK hash set is more performant.

Comment: @maraca, Edit 8's code is different. You can test with that. Have you measured?

Comment: @Koray what is different exactly? I don't see it, except from 2 more modulo checks added in dp part and early escape with modulo in preprocessing part (added that one too, and no change when gcd is 1), but the modulo with d[0] still performed better in my tests. You can run it against my new version to see if it comes from early escape.

Comment: @Koray I think I've seen it `if (val <= maxOK)` ... `else break;`, I think you cannot do that. Might give wrong results. When rounding down this will return the biggest multiple of the largest denominations smaller than amount which is smaller than amount. E.g. rounding down a = 33 with d = {8, 12} returns 24 or not?

Comment: @maraca it returns 32. You may check if you like. Test code includes validation with your function (tested with my old confirmed slower trys as well). Yes we can do that, and no it won't give wrong result. Why would it? The array is sorted. I'll test your last update when I find time.

Comment: @Koray yes, I somehow thought it breaks everything, but it's only the inner loop. But I was right that this was what makes the difference. Added that break to my code now too, should be faster now because less overhead (hsOK, size of bit array) and same (your) logic for dp part. Except for gcd reduction and the modulo escape in the dp part. Here my tests showed mine to be faster, but the difference is smaller than the gain from the early loop break (therefore your solution outperformed mine).

Answer (score 4):

```
    private static void test()
    {
        var amount = 61;
        int[] denoms = new int[] { 20, 50 };
        int up = RoundAmount(amount, denoms, true);//->70
        int down = RoundAmount(amount, denoms, false);//->60
    }
    private static int RoundAmount(int amount, int[] denoms, bool roundUp)
    {   
        HashSet<int> hs = new HashSet<int>(denoms);
        bool added = true;
        while (added)
        {
            added = false;
            var arr = hs.ToArray();
            foreach (int v1 in arr)
                foreach (int v2 in arr)
                    if ((v1 < amount) && (v2 < amount) && (hs.Add(v1 + v2)))
                        added = true;
        }

        int retval = roundUp ? int.MaxValue : int.MinValue;
        foreach (int v in hs)
        {
            if (roundUp)
            {
                if ((v < retval) && (v >= amount))
                    retval = v;
            }
            else
            {
                if ((v > retval) && (v <= amount))
                    retval = v;
            }
        }
        return retval;
    }
```

**Edit 7**
Edit 6 had a bug if a "0" denom exists. I examined @maraca's code in detail (its just great I think) and inspired on that, I've tried some optimizations on my code. Here are the performance comparisons. (I've tried to convert maraca's code to c#, I hope I ve done it right.)

```
private static int REPEAT = 100;
private static int[] D_COUNT = { 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100 };
private static int[] D_MAX = { 100, 10000, 1000000 };
private static int[] A_MAX = { 10000, 1000000 };
private static void testR()
{            
    Random r = new Random();
    long wMaraca = 0;
    long wKoray = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < REPEAT; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < D_COUNT.Length; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < D_MAX.Length; k++)
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < A_MAX.Length; l++)
                {
                    int[] d = new int[D_COUNT[j]];
                    for (int m = 0; m < d.Length; m++)
                        d[m] = r.Next(D_MAX[k]);
                    int a = r.Next(A_MAX[l]);

                    Stopwatch maraca = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                    int m1 = RoundAmount_maraca(a, d, false);
                    int m2 = RoundAmount_maraca(a, d, true);
                    maraca.Stop();
                    wMaraca += maraca.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                    
                    Stopwatch koray = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                    int k1 = RoundAmount_koray(a, d, false);
                    int k2 = RoundAmount_koray(a, d, true);
                    koray.Stop();
                    wKoray += koray.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                                                
                    if ((m1 != k1) || (m2 != k2))
                    {
                        throw new Exception("something is wrong!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //some results with debug compile
    //try1
    //maraca: 50757 msec
    //koray:  19188 msec
    //try2
    //maraca: 52623 msec
    //koray:  19102 msec
    //try3
    //maraca: 57139 msec
    //koray:  18952 msec
    //try4
    //maraca: 64911 msec
    //koray:  21070 msec
}
private static int RoundAmount_koray(int amount, int[] denoms, bool roundUp)
{
    List<int> lst = denoms.ToList();
    lst.Sort();
    if (amount < lst[0])
        return roundUp ? lst[0] : 0;
    HashSet<int> hs = new HashSet<int>();
    for (int i = 0, count = lst.Count; i < count; i++)
    {
        int v = lst[i];
        if (v != 0)
        {
            if (v > amount && !roundUp)
                break;
            if (hs.Add(v))
            {
                if (amount % v == 0)
                    return amount;
                else
                    for (int j = i + 1; j < count; j++)
                        if (lst[j] != 0)
                            if (v % lst[j] == 0)
                                lst[j] = 0;
                            else if (amount % (v + lst[j]) == 0)
                                return amount;
            }
        }
    }
    denoms = hs.ToArray();           

    HashSet<int> hsOK = new HashSet<int>(denoms);
    Stack<int> st = new Stack<int>(denoms);
    BitArray ba = new BitArray(amount + denoms.Max() * 2 + 1);
    int minOK = amount - denoms.Min();
    while (st.Count > 0)
    {
        int v1 = st.Pop();
        foreach (int v2 in denoms)
        {
            int val = v1 + v2;
            if (!ba.Get(val))
            {
                if (amount % val == 0)
                    return amount;
                ba.Set(val, true);
                if (val < amount)
                    st.Push(val);
                if (val >= minOK)
                    hsOK.Add(val);
            }
        }
    }

    if (!roundUp)
    {
        int retval = 0;
        foreach (int v in hsOK)
            if (v > retval && v <= amount)
                retval = v;
        return retval;
    }
    else
    {
        int retval = int.MaxValue;
        foreach (int v in hsOK)
            if (v < retval && v >= amount)
                retval = v;
        return retval;
    }
}
private static int RoundAmount_maraca(int a, int[] d, bool up)
{
    d = d.ToArray();
    Array.Sort(d);

    if (a < d[0])
        return up ? d[0] : 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < d.Length; i++)
    {
        if (d[i] == 0)
            continue;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < d.Length; j++)
            if (d[j] % d[i] == 0)
                d[j] = 0;
        if (d[i] > a && !up)
            break;
        d[count++] = d[i];
        if (d[i] > a)
            break;
    }
    if (count == 1)
        return (!up ? a : (a + d[0] - 1)) / d[0] * d[0];
    int gcd = euclid(d[1], d[0]);
    for (int i = 2; i < count && gcd > 1; i++)
        gcd = euclid(d[i], gcd);
    if (up)
        a = (a + gcd - 1) / gcd;
    else
        a /= gcd;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        d[i] /= gcd;
        if (a % d[i] == 0)
            return a * gcd;
    }
    var set = new HashSet<int>();
    set.Add(0);
    int last = 0;
    for (int n = d[0]; ; n++)
    {
        if (!up && n > a)
            return last * gcd;
        for (int i = 0; i < count && n - d[i] >= 0; i++)
        {
            if (set.Contains(n - d[i]))
            {
                if (n >= a)
                    return n * gcd;
                if ((a - n) % d[0] == 0)
                    return a * gcd;
                set.Add(n);
                last = n;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
private static int euclid(int a, int b)
{
    while (b != 0)
    {
        int h = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = h;
    }
    return a;
}
```

**Edit - Maraca in c#**

Maraca's last edit clearly outperforms all! I have tried to prepare a better c# conversion of his code + added a ulong version. (int version is ~1.6 times faster than the ulong version)

```
#region maraca int
private static int RoundAmount_maraca(int a, int[] d0, bool up)
{
    int[] d = new int[d0.Length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(d0, 0, d, 0, d.Length * sizeof(int));
    Array.Sort(d);
    
    if (a < d[0])
        return up ? d[0] : 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < d.Length; i++)
    {
        if (d[i] == 0)
            continue;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < d.Length; j++)
            if (d[j] % d[i] == 0)
                d[j] = 0;
        if (d[i] > a && !up)
            break;
        d[count++] = d[i];
        if (d[i] > a)
            break;
    }
    if (count == 1)
        return (!up ? a : (a + d[0] - 1)) / d[0] * d[0];
    int gcd = euclid(d[1], d[0]);
    for (int i = 2; i < count && gcd > 1; i++)
        gcd = euclid(d[i], gcd);
    if (up)
        a = (a + gcd - 1) / gcd;
    else
        a /= gcd;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        d[i] /= gcd;
        if (a % d[i] == 0)
            return a * gcd;
    }
    int best = !up ? d[count - 1] : ((a + d[0] - 1) / d[0] * d[0]);
    if (d[count - 1] > a)
    {
        if (d[count - 1] < best)
            best = d[count - 1];
        count--;
    }
    var st = new Stack<int>();
    BitArray ba = new BitArray(a+1);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        ba.Set(d[i], true);
        st.Push(d[i]);
    }
    while (st.Count > 0)
    {
        int v1 = st.Pop();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            int val = v1 + d[i];
            if (val <= a && !ba.Get(val))
            {
                if ((a - val) % d[0] == 0)
                    return a * gcd;
                ba.Set(val, true);
                st.Push(val);
                if (!up && val > best)
                    best = val;
            }
            else if (up && val > a && val < best)
                best = val;
        }
    }
    return best * gcd;
}
private static int euclid(int a, int b)
{
    while (b != 0)
    {
        int h = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = h;
    }
    return a;
}
#endregion
#region maraca ulong
private static ulong RoundAmount_maraca_ulong(ulong a, ulong[] d0, bool up)
{
    ulong[] d = new ulong[d0.Length];
    Buffer.BlockCopy(d0, 0, d, 0, d.Length * sizeof(ulong));
    Array.Sort(d);

    if (a < d[0])
        return up ? d[0] : 0ul;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < d.Length; i++)
    {
        if (d[i] == 0ul)
            continue;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < d.Length; j++)
            if (d[j] % d[i] == 0ul)
                d[j] = 0ul;
        if (d[i] > a && !up)
            break;
        d[count++] = d[i];
        if (d[i] > a)
            break;
    }
    if (count == 1)
        return (!up ? a : (a + d[0] - 1ul)) / d[0] * d[0];
    ulong gcd = euclid(d[1], d[0]);
    for (int i = 2; i < count && gcd > 1; i++)
        gcd = euclid(d[i], gcd);
    if (up)
        a = (a + gcd - 1ul) / gcd;
    else
        a /= gcd;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        d[i] /= gcd;
        if (a % d[i] == 0ul)
            return a * gcd;
    }
    ulong best = !up ? d[count - 1] : ((a + d[0] - 1ul) / d[0] * d[0]);
    if (d[count - 1] > a)
    {
        if (d[count - 1] < best)
            best = d[count - 1];
        count--;
    }
    var st = new Stack<ulong>();
    UlongBitArray ba = new UlongBitArray(a + 1ul);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        ba.Set(d[i], true);
        st.Push(d[i]);
    }
    while (st.Count > 0)
    {
        ulong v1 = st.Pop();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            ulong val = v1 + d[i];
            if (val <= a && !ba.Get(val))
            {
                if ((a - val) % d[0] == 0ul)
                    return a * gcd;
                ba.Set(val, true);
                st.Push(val);
                if (!up && val > best)
                    best = val;
            }
            else if (up && val > a && val < best)
                best = val;
        }
    }
    return best * gcd;
}
private static ulong euclid(ulong a, ulong b)
{
    while (b != 0)
    {
        ulong h = a % b;
        a = b;
        b = h;
    }
    return a;
}
class UlongBitArray
{
    ulong[] bits;
    public UlongBitArray(ulong length)
    {
        this.bits = new ulong[(length - 1ul) / 32ul + 1ul];
    }
    public bool Get(ulong index)
    {
        return (this.bits[index / 32ul] & (1ul << (int)(index % 32ul))) > 0ul;
    }
    public void Set(ulong index, bool val)
    {
        if (val)
            this.bits[index / 32ul] |= 1ul << (int)(index % 32ul);
        else
            this.bits[index / 32ul] &= ~(1ul << (int)(index % 32ul));
    }
}
#endregion
```

**Edit 8**

I have made some improvements and in random tests outperformed @maraca's latest update :) If you choose to use my custom **stack** class, please make measurements in **release** mode. (This custom stack class is of course much slower in debug mode but %5-15 faster than .NET's in relase mode. In my tests using the .NET Stack class did not change the performance comparison between two, its just an extra boost.)

```
        private delegate int RoundAmountDelegate(int amount, int[] denoms, bool roundUp);
        private static int REPEAT = 100;
        private static int[] D_COUNT = { 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100 };
        private static int[] D_MAX = { 100, 10000, 1000000 };
        private static int[] A_MAX = { 10000, 1000000 };
        private static void testR()
        {            
#if DEBUG
            while (true)
#endif
            {
                Random r = new Random();
                long wT1 = 0; RoundAmountDelegate func1 = RoundAmount_maraca;
                long wT2 = 0; RoundAmountDelegate func2 = RoundAmount_koray;
                for (int i = 0; i < REPEAT; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < D_COUNT.Length; j++)
                    {
                        for (int k = 0; k < D_MAX.Length; k++)
                        {
                            for (int l = 0; l < A_MAX.Length; l++)
                            {
                                int[] d = new int[D_COUNT[j]];
                                ulong[] dl = new ulong[D_COUNT[j]];
                                for (int m = 0; m < d.Length; m++)
                                {
                                    d[m] = r.Next(D_MAX[k]) + 1;
                                    dl[m] = (ulong)d[m];
                                }
                                int a = r.Next(A_MAX[l]);
                                ulong al = (ulong)a;

                                Stopwatch w1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                                int m1 = func1(a, d, false);
                                int m2 = func1(a, d, true);
                                w1.Stop();
                                wT1 += w1.ElapsedMilliseconds;

                                Stopwatch w2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                                int k1 = func2(a, d, false);
                                int k2 = func2(a, d, true);
                                w2.Stop();
                                wT2 += w2.ElapsedMilliseconds;

                                if ((m1 != k1) || (m2 != k2))
                                {
#if !DEBUG
                                    MessageBox.Show("error");
#else
                                    throw new Exception("something is wrong!");
#endif
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                //some results with release compile

                //maraca:                       1085 msec
                //koray(with .NET Stack<int>):   801 msec

                //maraca:                       1127 msec
                //koray(with .NET Stack<int>):   741 msec

                //maraca:                        989 msec
                //koray(with .NET Stack<int>):   736 msec

                //maraca:                        962 msec
                //koray(with .NET Stack<int>):   632 msec

                //-------------------------------------------
                //maraca:                     1045 msec
                //koray(with custom stack):    674 msec

                //maraca:                     1060 msec
                //koray(with custom stack):    606 msec

                //maraca:                     1175 msec
                //koray(with custom stack):    711 msec

                //maraca:                      878 msec
                //koray(with custom stack):    699 msec

#if !DEBUG
                MessageBox.Show(wT1 + "  " + wT2 + "  %" + (double)wT2 / (double)wT1 * 100d);
#endif
            }
        }

        #region Koray
        private static int RoundAmount_koray(int amount, int[] denoms, bool roundUp)
        {
            int[] sorted = new int[denoms.Length];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(denoms, 0, sorted, 0, sorted.Length * sizeof(int));
            Array.Sort(sorted);
            int minD = sorted[0];
            if (amount < minD)
                return roundUp ? minD : 0;
            HashSet<int> hs = new HashSet<int>();
            for (int i = 0, count = sorted.Length; i < count; i++)
            {
                int v = sorted[i];
                if (v != 0)
                {
                    if (!roundUp && v > amount)
                        break;
                    else if (hs.Add(v))
                    {
                        if (amount % v == 0)
                            return amount;
                        else
                            for (int j = i + 1; j < count; j++)
                                if (sorted[j] != 0)
                                    if (v % sorted[j] == 0)
                                        sorted[j] = 0;
                                    else if (amount % (v + sorted[j]) == 0)
                                        return amount;
                    }
                }
            }
            denoms = new int[hs.Count];
            int k = 0;
            foreach (var v in hs)
                denoms[k++] = v;

            HashSet<int> hsOK = new HashSet<int>(denoms);
            stack st = new stack(denoms);
            //Stack<int> st = new Stack<int>(denoms);
            BitArray ba = new BitArray(amount + denoms[denoms.Length - 1] * 2 + 1);
            int minOK = roundUp ? amount : amount - minD;
            int maxOK = roundUp ? amount + minD : amount;
            while (st.Count > 0)
            {
                int v1 = st.Pop();
                foreach (int v2 in denoms)
                {
                    int val = v1 + v2;
                    if (val <= maxOK)
                    {
                        if (!ba.Get(val))
                        {
                            if (amount % val == 0)
                                return amount;

                            int diff = amount - val;
                            if (diff % v1 == 0 || diff % v2 == 0)
                                return amount;

                            ba.Set(val, true);
                            if (val < amount)
                                st.Push(val);
                            if (val >= minOK)
                                hsOK.Add(val);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        break;
                }
            }

            if (!roundUp)
            {
                int retval = 0;
                foreach (int v in hsOK)
                    if (v > retval && v <= amount)
                        retval = v;
                return retval;
            }
            else
            {
                int retval = int.MaxValue;
                foreach (int v in hsOK)
                    if (v < retval && v >= amount)
                        retval = v;
                return retval;
            }
        }
        private sealed class stack
        {
            int[] _array;
            public int Count;
            public stack()
            {
                this._array = new int[0];
            }
            public stack(int[] arr)
            {
                this.Count = arr.Length;
                this._array = new int[this.Count*2];
                Buffer.BlockCopy(arr, 0, this._array, 0, this.Count * sizeof(int));
            }
            public void Push(int item)
            {
                if (this.Count == this._array.Length)
                {
                    int[] destinationArray = new int[2 * this.Count];
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(this._array, 0, destinationArray, 0, this.Count * sizeof(int));
                    this._array = destinationArray;
                }
                this._array[this.Count++] = item;
            }
            public int Pop()
            {
                return this._array[--this.Count];
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #region Maraca
        private static int RoundAmount_maraca(int a, int[] d0, bool up)
        {
            int[] d = new int[d0.Length];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(d0, 0, d, 0, d.Length * sizeof(int));
            Array.Sort(d);

            if (a < d[0])
                return up ? d[0] : 0;
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < d.Length; i++)
            {
                if (d[i] == 0)
                    continue;
                for (int j = i + 1; j < d.Length; j++)
                    if (d[j] % d[i] == 0)
                        d[j] = 0;
                if (d[i] > a && !up)
                    break;
                d[count++] = d[i];
                if (d[i] > a)
                    break;
            }
            if (count == 1)
                return (!up ? a : (a + d[0] - 1)) / d[0] * d[0];
            int gcd = euclid(d[1], d[0]);
            for (int i = 2; i < count && gcd > 1; i++)
                gcd = euclid(d[i], gcd);
            if (up)
                a = (a + gcd - 1) / gcd;
            else
                a /= gcd;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                d[i] /= gcd;
                if (a % d[i] == 0)
                    return a * gcd;
            }
            int best = !up ? d[count - 1] : ((a + d[0] - 1) / d[0] * d[0]);
            if (d[count - 1] > a)
            {
                if (d[count - 1] < best)
                    best = d[count - 1];
                count--;
            }
            var st = new Stack<int>();
            BitArray ba = new BitArray(a + 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                ba.Set(d[i], true);
                st.Push(d[i]);
            }
            while (st.Count > 0)
            {
                int v1 = st.Pop();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    int val = v1 + d[i];
                    if (val <= a && !ba.Get(val))
                    {
                        if ((a - val) % d[0] == 0)
                            return a * gcd;
                        ba.Set(val, true);
                        st.Push(val);
                        if (!up && val > best)
                            best = val;
                    }
                    else if (up && val > a && val < best)
                        best = val;
                }
            }
            return best * gcd;
        }
        private static int euclid(int a, int b)
        {
            while (b != 0)
            {
                int h = a % b;
                a = b;
                b = h;
            }
            return a;
        }
        #endregion
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145820/discussion-on-answer-by-koray-rounding-amount-with-available-set-of-denomination).

Comment: *RoundAmount_koray* seems to be fastest at the moment. It can easily be converted to ulong using long version of bitarray from my previos edit.

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard Knapsack problem and you can google it to refer to its wiki page for its concept.

I think your problem can be splitted to two parts.

**Do Knapsack for denominations.**

Use `f[i]` to represent the last denomination used to construct amount `i`, and `f[i]==-1` means that `i` is not able to get.

```
fill f with -1
f[0] = 0
for i from 0 to target_amount + min(denoms) - 1
    for j from 0 to denoms.size()
        if f[i - denoms[j]] != -1
        {
            f[i] = denoms[j]
            break
        }
```

**Find nearest amount based on `roundUp`.**

- `roundUp == true`

Starting from `target_amount`, ascendingly find a `f[i]` which is not `-1`.

- `roundUp == false`

Starting from `target_amount`, descendingly find a `f[i]` which is not `-1`.

**Optional: find which denominations construct your target amount**

Backtrack your `f[target_amount]`.

Comment: Won't it get failed in the first loop itself because `if f[i - denoms[j]]` will result in `OutOfRange` exception?

Comment: I have got this algo to work, only problem is it's performance, But thanks It was very much helpful +1 :(

Comment: Actually it is *not* a standard Knapsack problem.  It is in fact much simpler than that, it is just a GCD rounding problem.

Comment: if you have $0.2 and $0.5 coins, it's not a GCD problem, because you can't make $0.1 or $0.3

Answer (score 1):

Just fill array of length `amount + smallestdenomination + 1` with possible combinations of coins (standard dynamic programming problem).

Then walk this array from `amount` index in rounding direction.

Delphi example

```
 var
  A : array of Integer;
  Denoms: array of Integer;
  coin, amount, idx, i, Maxx: Integer;
  roundUp: Boolean;
  s: string;
begin
  amount := 29;
  SetLength(Denoms, 2);
  Denoms[0] := 7;
  Denoms[1] := 13;
  Maxx := amount + MinIntValue(Denoms);
  SetLength(A, Maxx + 1);
  A[0] := 1;

  for coin in Denoms do begin
    for i := 0 to Maxx - coin do
       if A[i] <> 0 then
          A[i + coin] := coin;
  end;

  roundUp := True;
  idx := amount;
  i := 2 * Ord(roundUp) - 1;// 1 for  roundUp=true, -1 for false
  while A[idx] = 0 do  //scan for nonzero entry
    idx := idx + i;

  s := '';
  while idx > 0 do begin     //roll back to get components of this sum
    s := s + Format('%d ', [A[idx]]);
    idx := idx - A[idx];
  end;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(s);
```

outputs `13 13 7` combination for `roundUp := True;` and `7 7 7 7` otherwise.

(Code does not seek for "optimal" solution)

Example for coins 3 and 5:

```
[0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 5, 3, 0, 5, 3, 5]
```

To find what coins make cell 8, step down by cell value:by 5 then by 3.

Comment: Ok, while filling that array, how would I find possible combination of coins?

Comment: Write coin value in the cell. Example added

Comment: A bit confused. Firstly, How do I fill the array with possible combination of coins? secondly, in your example, how did you constructed that array?

Comment: Made working example (hope that Delphi code is understandable)

Comment: Thanks @Mbo, Yeah makes more sense now +1

Answer (score 1):

The [Coin Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem) is a well-researched topic and I would like to reference some papers where you can probably find better solutions:

- [The Money Changing Problem Revisited](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f03f/c4d849527e1f45aee0cadfd8d8df96ac8dfe.pdf)
- [Coin Problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CoinProblem.html)

Also, using C# (statically typed language) will restrict you from having the most efficient algorithm over a dynamically typed language. If you plan to go down that route, you can have a look at this website [The Frobenius problem](http://mathsjavascript.free.fr/frobenius_9_page.html). You can right click and inspect the code *(though I really didn't understand much having no experience of javascript)*

Anyhow, this is how I would tackle the problem in C#:

```
private static List<int> _denominations = new List<int>() { 1000, 5000 };
private static int _denominationMin = _denominations[0];

static void Main()
{
    bool roundDown = false;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter number: ");
    int input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    if(roundDown)
    {
        for(int i = input; i > _denominationMin; i--)
        {
            if(Check(0,0,i))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Number: {0}", i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = input; i < int.MaxValue; i++)
        {
            if (Check(0, 0, i))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Number: {0}", i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    Console.Read();
}

static bool Check(int highest, int sum, int goal)
{
    //Bingo!
    if (sum == goal)
    {
        return true;
    }
    //Oops! exceeded here
    if (sum > goal)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Loop through _denominations.
    foreach (int value in _denominations)
    {
        // Add higher or equal amounts.
        if (value >= highest)
        {
            if(Check(value, sum + value, goal))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Worked well with {4,6} for input 19999, so I don't think it is all that bad. Surely has scope for improvements for not running into `Stackoverflow Exception`. One could half the input or quarter it. Or subtract a number that has factors whose subset are the denominations. Also, important to have the denominations sorted and contain no multiples of another entry E.x. {4, 6, 8} -> {4, 6}.

Anyhow, if I have time I will try to make it more efficient. Just wanted to provide an alternate solution.